# How to include a custom-switch in a navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to include a switch control in may navbar, but the display isn't perfect as I can't adjust the alignement of the label and of the switch. What is the best way to achieve that ?

Here is my working code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="nav-item custom-control custom-switch mr-sm-2" >
            <input type="checkbox" class="navbar-toggler form-control custom-control-input" id="transparency" checked>
            <label class="navbar-text custom-control-label small" for="transparency">Transparency</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily achieve that by adding a `line-height` property to your custom-control class

```
.custom-control {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.5rem;

    line-height: 7px;  #just add this property


    padding-left: 1.5rem;
}
```

check this one

```css
.custom-control { 
line-height: 7px; 
}
```

```html
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">First</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="nav-item custom-control custom-switch mr-sm-2" >
                <input type="checkbox" class="navbar-toggler form-control custom-control-input" id="transparency" checked>
                <label class="navbar-text custom-control-label small" for="transparency">Transparency</label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </header>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `padding` for `label` Or add this class `p-0` for `label`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="nav-item custom-control custom-switch mr-sm-2" >
            <input type="checkbox" class="navbar-toggler form-control custom-control-input" id="transparency" checked>
            <label class="navbar-text custom-control-label p-0 small" for="transparency">Transparency</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The result looks fine and may follow the flex philosophy. But I prefer the CSS adjustement for better readability (for me).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">First</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
     <li>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="nav-item custom-control custom-switch mr-sm-2" >
            <input type="checkbox" class="navbar-toggler form-control custom-control-input" id="transparency" checked>
            <label class="navbar-text custom-control-label small" for="transparency">Transparency</label>
          </div>
        </form>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

and add this css in your label

```
.navbar-text
{
      line-height: 8px;
}
```

Here is your working demo

https://jsfiddle.net/cv4qoerd/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a margin to the custom swith in order to align it with the text:

```css
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before{
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">First</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline">
              <div class="nav-item custom-control custom-switch mr-sm-2 d-flex align-items-center" >
                <input type="checkbox" class="navbar-toggler form-control custom-control-input" id="transparency" checked>
                <label class="navbar-text custom-control-label small" for="transparency">Transparency</label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </header>
      </body>
```